# /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string in dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, shell, dockerfile, posix

I need to have variable inside file constants.js with quotes ('here variable'). Trying do it in dockerfile, but getting his error, can't figure it out. Tried escaping quotes, but its not working. Doing it with double quotes - works, but I need single. Any idea?

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim
    
ENV GIT_BRANCH=develop
ENV GIT_COMMIT_TAG=26bf94075e6d5f2c575a291680e905e15aa0c81f
    
COPY constants.js .
    
RUN { \
        /bin/bash -c '{ \
             sed -i -r "s/^([[:blank:]]*APP_VERSION:[[:blank:]]*).*/\1\'\${GIT_COMMIT_TAG:0:7}\',/" constants.js ; \
        }' ; \    
    }
    
CMD ["sleep", "inf"]
```

File constants.js looks like:

```js
const constants = {
  APP_NAME: 'app',
  APP_VERSION: '10.0.0',
};
module.exports = {
  constants,
};
```

#UPDATE1

Longer

```
/bin/bash -c
```

in Dockerfile:

```sh
if [ ! -z "$GIT_BRANCH" ]; then \
    GIT_BRANCH="${GIT_BRANCH}/" ; \
fi ; \
echo "${GIT_BRANCH}${GIT_COMMIT_TAG:0:7}" > .release.txt ; \
sed -i -r "s/^([[:blank:]]*APP_VERSION:[[:blank:]]*).*/\1'\${GIT_COMMIT_TAG:0:7}',/" constants.js ; \
appver=$(awk '"'"'/APP_VERSION/ { print $2 }'"'"' constants.js) ; \
echo "${appver:1:-2}" > .appversion ; \
```

so thats why I use bash -c.

Comment: Hmm... it's hard to keep track of the quoting. Did you try double backslashes before the single quotation marks around `GIT_COMMIT_TAG`? `\\'\${GIT_COMMIT_TAG:0:7}\\'`

Comment: Why do you run /bin/bash? What for? What's the point? Why not just the command?

Comment: @maitza Why not just `RUN sed ...`?!

Comment: Sorry, its not just sed in this, I do more bash commands, that why I use bash -c.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify `/bin/bash -c`. Instead, just use `RUN` and immediately the command you need to execute. It is necessary to remove a few extra `/`. The final `Dockerfile` is given below

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim

ENV GIT_BRANCH=develop
ENV GIT_COMMIT_TAG=26bf94075e6d5f2c575a291680e905e15aa0c81f

COPY constants.js .

RUN sed -i -r "s/^([[:blank:]]*APP_VERSION:[[:blank:]]*).*/\1\'$GIT_COMMIT_TAG:0:7',/" constants.js ;

CMD ["sleep", "inf"]
```

Resulted `constants.js` file

```js
const constants = {
  APP_NAME: 'app',
  APP_VERSION: '26bf94075e6d5f2c575a291680e905e15aa0c81f:0:7',
};

module.exports = {
  constants,
};
```

**UPD #1**

For execute some logic that does not fit on one line, the best solution would be to put it in a separate bash script.

Thus, you add `setup.sh` and change the `Dockerfile`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim

ENV GIT_BRANCH=develop
ENV GIT_COMMIT_TAG=26bf94075e6d5f2c575a291680e905e15aa0c81f

COPY ["constants.js", "setup.sh", "./"]

RUN chmod +x ./setup.sh && ./setup.sh
```

**setup.sh**

```sh
if [ ! -z "$GIT_BRANCH" ]; then
    GIT_BRANCH="${GIT_BRANCH}/"
fi

CUTTED_GIT_COMMIT_TAG=$(echo "$GIT_COMMIT_TAG" | cut -c -7)

echo "${GIT_BRANCH}${CUTTED_GIT_COMMIT_TAG}" > .release.txt
sed -i -r "s/^([[:blank:]]*APP_VERSION:[[:blank:]]*).*/\1\'${CUTTED_GIT_COMMIT_TAG}',/" constants.js

APP_VERSION=$(awk '"'"'/APP_VERSION/ { print $2 }'"'"' constants.js)
CUTTED_APP_VERSION=$(echo "$appver" | cut -c 2- | rev | cut -c 1- | rev)
echo $CUTTED_APP_VERSION > .appversion
```

Comment: I use bash -c because it's not one command. Probably, my bad, I shorted this Dockerfile.

Comment: @maitza, try this method and report success)

Comment: `./setup.sh: 5: ./sed.sh: Bad substitution` because of $, doing /$ working fine, but then its not getting it as variable, just as string..

Comment: :0:7 its just cutting long commit hash, to short (7).

Comment: and doing it just by bash script, its working, but using Dockerfile looks like that

Comment: it didint helped. Answear is near this comment.

Comment: @maitza, I cut string and updated the answer. Check if everything is working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so sed should looks like this:

```
sed -r -i  "/APP_VERSION/ s/'\''(.*)'\''/'\''${GIT_COMMIT_TAG:0:7}'\''/" constants.js ; \
```

Then its working like it should.